# How to convert img src into picture using ajax and C#

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have my html, but i'm so confused how can i convert an image source to picture, i made some code below, but i didn't why it is not able to convert the string(img src) to byte, help me,

**HTML**

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, ...>
```

**JQUERY**

```
var getimg = parentDiv.find("img");\
var pic = getimg.attr('src');
var filebase = pic.split(";");
filebase[1] = filebase[1].replace("base64,", "");
console.log(filebase[1]);
var realname  = "picsample.jpg"
console.log(pic);
$.ajax({
   url: '/FileBrowser/UploadImage',
   type: 'POST',
   datatype: 'json',
   data: { file: filebase[1], filename:realname},
   cache: false,
   beforeSend: function() {

   },
   success: function(result) {
       console.log(result);
   },
   complete: function() {

   },
   error: function(error) {

   }
});
```

**[HttpPost]**

```
public string UploadImage(string file, string filename){
    string filepath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Media"), filename);

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Create)){

        using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs)){

            byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(file);
            bw.Write(data);
            bw.Close();
        }

    }
    return "Data";
}
```

Comment: You're going to need to add some more information. You want to display the image where? On a webpage, in a program page? Do you want to save it to the user's pc?

Comment: all i want it sir is to save the image in my folder media which is include in my program folder

Comment: the picture already there once i run the program but image file currupted

Comment: Your img src seems to be wrong. It should look like this: `C:\Users\AJ\Documents\picture.jpg` or `http://www.domain.com/images/picture.jpg`

Comment: sir the img scr i put there is not a usual link, it is a link consists of too many characters and symbol, link this  <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhlgCWAOZqAJWVlZ2dnaampq6urre3t7+/v8jIyNDQ0OHh4dnZ2erq6vLy8v39/enp6f7+/vz8/Pj4+NjY2M...>

Comment: i do not know sir how to convert that scr, i encountered some error, "The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters."

Comment: thanks alot again sir , :) at last i finished it